# How to make QLabel expand width geometry to accommodate text

Tags: qt, qlabel

I currently have a QLabel that has some text in it. However when I put some text in it that exceeds its geometrical width then that extra text is not displayed. I do not want to enable wordwrap since I want the QLabel to expand horizontally. Is there anyway that Qlabel could increase its geometrical width based on its content.

Comment: Have you tried appropriate size policy for the label like expanding or minimum expanding?

Comment: Yes I did try setting those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [QWidget::adjustSize()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize) everytime you change the content of your label. I can't  elaborate on other possible answers due to lack of information, but that will probably do the trick.